# Laravel 4 pagination tags change

Tags: tags, pagination, laravel, laravel-4

Is some way to change structure pagination tags in Laravel 4?

I am creating the pagination links using the links method:

```
 <?php echo $data->links(); ?>
```

HTML is like this:

```
 <div class="pagination">
  <ul>
   <li>
     <a href="#">1</a>
   </li>
   <li>
     <a href="#">2</a>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
```

For example remove unordered HTML list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit `app/config/view.php` and change the `pagination` option to be one of your views, like 'pages'.

The create your `pages.php` view.

The default pagination is below. I'd start with that and start tweaking it as you need.

```
<?php
    $presenter = new Illuminate\Pagination\BootstrapPresenter($paginator);

    $trans = $environment->getTranslator();
?>

<?php if ($paginator->getLastPage() > 1): ?>
    <ul class="pager">
        <?php
            echo $presenter->getPrevious($trans->trans('pagination.previous'));

            echo $presenter->getNext($trans->trans('pagination.next'));
        ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thx for reaction it helped me BUT in this view isn't everything some tags are binding before in 'Illuminate\Pagination\BootstrapPresenter.php' (example: li tag). Is some nice method to change this? Or i can rewrite it directly in this file but this way does not seem correct...

Comment: '<div class="pagination">' with '<a>' inside only.. classes can be deafult.